# I accidentally uploaded .env file with google key in it to github but edited the file and removed the key. Can the change be seen somewhere?

Tags: git, github

So I created an .env file and had the impression that .env files do not get commited, however, it did. Since it contains a Google API key, I edited the .env file straight away and removed the key from it, however, I wonder if there's a way for people to see what changes have been done to that .env file ( like removing text which in my case is the API key )

Comment: Yes, you can see the commits for a repo on `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commits/<branch>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: Yes I can indeed see the commit. Can you point me to which command should I use to remove it as the recommended post contains loads of commands which don't make too much sense to me.

Comment: The only good move is to revoke the key. History doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

revoke the current key and create a new one (for safety reasons)

you can remove it by filtering the branch you are working on by using
`git filter-branch`

you can find about it in details here

https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

You **must** consider this key already exposed, revoke it and create a new one.

After that, it's at your convenience if you want to take time and efforts to remove it from your history...

For the future, you could use [git-secrets](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets) to prevent committing it as it is explained in [google best practices to keep key safe](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/help-keep-your-google-cloud-service-account-keys-safe)